# Tileable object placement algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I've used noise algorithms like Perlin noise that produce textures that are tileable. I'm working on a tool for randomly placing objects on a canvas. The problem is the results do not tile i.e. if I take the image and repeat it on a grid, there are clear seams.

What I have so far is very basic:

```
height = 1024
width = 1024
N = int(width * height / 4096)
np.random.seed(5000)
x_generated = np.random.uniform(0, width, N)
y_generated = np.random.uniform(0, height, N)
```

If I could use the perlin noise as a basis for this, I could probably get a tileable pattern, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

Which algorithm can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Here is an example of the object placement I'm talking about. Each square is what I mean by "object". It could be any shape and pattern placed on the canvas. You can see, at the edges, some of the squares go outside the bounds. If I were to repeat/tile this image in a rendering engine, there would be clear seams where the tiles meet and the squares are cutoff.

Perlin noise doesn't have this issue. You can tile it and there are no seams. I want to find a way to eliminate this "seam".

Maybe it's just a case of having an if statement check the bounds of each square when placing and if its out of the frame, don't place that object? It just doesn't feel super clean to do that.

[image]

Comment: The code you have doesn't create any visible seams when you tile.  There must be a problem with the way you're using the output.

Comment: Are you asking for help tiling the data you generated or generating Perlin noise?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Maybe I'm just being stupid, but my understanding is that currently those random numbers don't follow any kind of pattern, they're just random, whereas Perlin Noise looks like distinct "clouds". The random function I'm using now should just produce noisy data with no visible "structure", no?

Comment: @BitsAreNumbersToo tiling the data. I already have a way to generate Perlin noise, but the problem is I don't know how to use the data to to influence object placement rather than generating a 2D texture. It may be something silly that I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of what you expect the output to be? Its difficult to imagine what you are trying to do with "object placement".

Comment: @BitsAreNumbersToo Edited original post

Comment: If one of your random squares is close enough to the edge to overlap it, then place an identical copy just beyond the opposite edge, to act as a wrapped-around version of it.  (A square in the corner, that overlaps two edges, will need three copies.)

Comment: @jasonharper ooh that would work well I think. I think I was too focused on the Perlin noise and trying to figure out a special algorithm when it's really that simple! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After following @jasonharper 's suggestion, I now do a check for the two diagonal corners of the square and add an additional square on the opposite side. The following is a snippet of how that works. It might have some corner cases (pun not intended) but it works for now.

```
        for x,y in zip(x_generated, y_generated)
            s = 1
            base_height = 50 * s
            base_width = 50 * s

            x0 = x - base_width/2
            x1 = x + base_width/2
            y0 = y - base_height/2
            y1 = y + base_height/2
            rect = self.can.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, outline="")

            flipx, flipy = False, False
            if x0 < xmin:
                x = x + width
                flipx = True
            elif x1 > xmax:
                x = x - width
                flipx = True
            if y0 < ymin:
                y = y + height
                flipy = True
            elif y1 > ymax:
                y = y - height
                flipy = True

            if flipx or flipy:
                x0 = x - base_width/2
                x1 = x + base_width/2
                y0 = y - base_height/2
                y1 = y + base_height/2
                rect = self.can.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, outline="")
```

[image]